# How to bridge from Binding<Date?> to Binding<Date> using Extension in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui, binding

**Context**

I am trying to bridge from `Binding<Date?>` to `Binding<Date>` using a `Extension` of `Binding`. However, I encountered a problem with the implementation below:

> Every time the `Binding` gets used within the app, it crashes telling me that `self.wrappedValue` was unexpectedly found `nil`, even though I am manually assigning `.now` to it if it is `nil`.

---

**Code**

```swift
public extension Binding where Value == Date? {
    var adapter: Binding<Date> {
        Binding<Date>(
            get: {
                if self.wrappedValue == nil { self.wrappedValue = .now }
                return self.wrappedValue! // CRASH
            },
            set: { self.wrappedValue = $0 }
        )
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can `self.wrappedValue` be `nil` after I manually set it to `.now` the line before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to update the value during `get` so change it to

```
get: {
    guard let value = self.wrappedValue else { return .now }                
    return value
}
```

Your current implementation should give you a purple warning saying

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

which is most likely the reason for the crash.

I always takes those purple warnings in my SwiftUI code very seriously and change the faulty code directly.